# Second ajax call is not working , the second one should be called only after the first one is sucess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two ajax calls , the second one should be triggered only after the first ajax is success.  Every time the first ajax returning sucess , but I always get error for the second one.

```
function proceedWithUnlock(target, address, PARAMS) {

  target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'processing....';
  target.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // in case of network errors this might not give reliable results
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText.match('Success')) {
          target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Success!!!';
          target.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
          lockTheNumber(target, address1, PARAMS1);
        } else {
          target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'FAILED';
          target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          target.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
      } else {
        target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'FAILED';
        target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        target.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
  client.open("POST", address);
  client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  client.send(PARAMS);

}

function lockTheNumber(target, address1, PARAMS1) {

  target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'processing....';
  target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';


  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // in case of network errors this might not give reliable results
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText.match('Success')) {
          target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Success11111!!!';
          target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
          target.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
        } else {
          target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'FAILED 1';
          target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
      } else {
        target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'UNABLE TO BLOCK 2';
        target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
  client.open("POST", address);

  client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  client.send(PARAMS);
}
```

Error Message: "Error in completing operation "

Comment: So is the first Ajax call throwing the error? What is the status code?

Comment: Status code is 200 , but i am getting error on page. this is for the second ajax call

Comment: Do you have an issue with `address` and `address1` and same with `params` and `params1`?

Comment: issue is with while making the ajax call for address1.

Comment: address and params are good . only issue is with while making the ajax call for address1 and params1. i think something is missing , i am not getting the expected response, always getting error on page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new XMLHttpRequest object instead of reusing the old one. It is out of scope.

```
...
target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
...
```

Comment: Same issue even if i create new object.

Answer (score 0):

Your other `XMLHttpRequest` object is out of scope. You need to create a new object in your second function:

```
function lockTheNumber(target, address1, PARAMS1){

target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'processing....';
target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
```

Comment: Same issue even if i create new object.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the `jquery` tag so I assume you also can take advantage of the library. `JQuery` supports promises or in `JQuery` syntax it's called deferred.

This helps to structure ajax calls with the `then` operator
More information in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

JQuery also comes with a god wrapper for ajax calls.